# Is the Accel World manga the whole story?

Tags: accel-world

I found Accel World's [light novel](https://amzn.to/2Q7aeld) and the [manga](https://amzn.to/2QqkZ1m) on Amazon. My question: Is the manga the completed story? The manga has 8 volumes and the last one will be released on December 11, 2018. But the light novel has 17 volumes and the last one will be released on March 19, 2019.

So is the manga the whole story? Or do I need the light novels if I want to read the whole *Accel World*? If so, is it because the light novels have more volumes and will be released on 2019 while the manga is only up to 2018 so the manga does not have the completed story? Or is it otherwise?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thought I'd defer to someone which have read both but *I think this can be estimated based on how much both medium covers the anime*. According to Mangaupdates,

> the [Accel World manga](https://www.mangaupdates.com/series.html?id=59514) has 42 chapters and covers the anime from its first chapter up to **Chapter 24**

while

> the [Accel World light novel](https://www.mangaupdates.com/series.html?id=72060) covers the anime from the first volume up to **Volume 4 Chapter 12**.

Based on this, if we were to estimate that 4 light novel volumes is equivalent to 24 manga chapters, then *the manga, approximately, is until around the 8th or 9th light novel volume.* Since the light novel currently has 22 volumes, there's a lot of content the manga has not covered.

So if you want to stay up-to-date with the story, I suggest you **read the light novel**, which is also **where the manga is based on**.